# HTTPS em arquitetura Rest

Tags: angularjs, rest, restful, spring-boot, ssl

Possuo um web service escrito utilizando o SpringBoot que roda no Tomcat e uma aplicação cliente escrita em AngularJS que roda no Apache2.
Gostaria de saber como funciona a questão de SSL para este caso. O SSL deve ser configurado no Tomcat e no Apache2? Se sim, eu consigo utilizar o mesmo certificado(as duas aplicações estão em um mesmo host)?
A minha necessidade é além da segurança em si ter o site em HTTPS.
Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: Pergunta rápida - existe alguma razão para você separar as duas aplicações? Você pode adicionar or arquivos da aplicação SPA como recursos estáticos/públicos no SpringBoot, não?

Comment: Até posso, mas pensando em uma arquitetura mais escalável para coisas futuras no meu caso devem ser separadas as duas aplicações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você pode usar o mesmo certificado, contanto que:

- Utilizar um certificado de domínio (`*.dominio.com.br`), que em termos gerais não é recomendável por questões de segurança, ou
- Um certificado com lista de múltiplos nomes-alvo alternativos - *multiple Subject Alternative Names*, ou *multiple SAN* - (`api.dominio.com.br` e `app.dominio.com.br`, por exemplo): 
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
  <sup>https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm</sup>

Você também precisará levar em consideração CORS, já que a comunicação ocorrerá entre sub-domínios.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Teria algum exemplo ou documentação sobre este caso de uso? Em minhas pesquisas não encontrei nada semelhante.

Comment: @DaniloAndrade eu não tenho nada à mão no momento, porém adicionei uma imagem e link de referência para SANs.

Comment: muito obrigado. Ajudou demais!

Comment: @DaniloAndrade Sempre um prazer ajudar!